# is there a way to provide instance name in cloudiy tosca?

Tags: cloudify

for cloudify tosca description with openstack plugin, how to define an instance name ?

```
type: cloudify.nodes.openstack.Server 
    properties:
      name: <node name>      <-- how to provide this?
```

cloudify composer gives error that "name" is not recognized in this property.
however HOT template allows such properties.

so is there a way to give a node name using cloudify tosca template for openstack ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is done this way

````
      name:
        type: string
        description: Name that should be given ```
````